# Copying node attribute to a new node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the xml like this:

```
<definitions xmlns:xxx="test.com" xmlns:yyy="test2.com" test="test">
</definitions>
```

which I need to convert like this:

```
<test xmlns:xxx="test.com" xmlns:yyy="test2.com" test="test">
</test>
```

I wrote an xslt like this:

```
<xsl:template match="definitions">
    <xsl:element name="test">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

this produces:

```
<test test="test">
</test>
```

but it doesnt contain `xmlns:xxx="test.com" xmlns:yyy="test2.com"` namespaces why?

How can I copy along with namespaces also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it doesnt contain xmlns:xxx="test.com" xmlns:yyy="test2.com" namespaces why?

It doesn't contain the namespace declarations because they are not used anywhere - so the XSLT processor does not output them.

> How can I copy along with namespaces also?

I don't see why you would want them - but if you insist, you could copy them explicitly:

```
<xsl:template match="definitions">
    <test>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | namespace::*" />
    </test>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that that it's not necessary to use `xsl:element` when the name of the element is known.

Answer (score 1):

The namespaces have to be declared in your XSL file, too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xxx="test.com"
    xmlns:yyy="test2.com">
```

Comment: This assumes the namespaces are known in advance. I thought the question was about copying **any** namespace declaration the input might contain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you just want to rename the element "definitions" to "test".
You can use something like this.

```
<xsl:template match="definitions">
<test>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
</test>
```