# Copy only the used namespaces using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to copy the namespaces of a tag which are only used using xslt?

For example I'm currently using:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//namespace::*" />
```

which is blindly copies all namespaces, but I want to copy only the used namespaces within the given tag, is it possible?

Comment: Well, what do you consider a use? Solely the use in a qualified node name or also the use in attribute or element values which are qualified names?

Comment: I want the last part 'element values which are qualified names'

Comment: As explained in [one of your previous questions on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36742861/3016153), the XSLT processor will automatically include all the required (i.e. used in the output)  namespace declarations, without you having to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy an element using xsl:copy-of, then all namespaces actually used on the element name or on one of its attributes will automatically be copied too (and other namespaces won't be copied).

Equally, xsl:copy "does the right thing" automatically.

If for some reason you want to copy all the namespace that are in-scope on an element $E without copying the element itself, you can use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$E/namespace::*"/>
```

Because you use the word "tag" rather than "element", I suspect that you don't have a deep understanding of the XDM data model. When manipulating namespaces, such an understanding is critical because it's not at all intuitive, and is probably the area where the data model differs most greatly from the "surface syntax". In particular you need to be aware that an element has namespace nodes for all the namespaces declared on the element itself and on any of its ancestors.